# I have applied both static and DHCP simultaneously and I cannot access my RPi now. What do I do to fix it?

Tags: static-ip

I am new to the RPi. I have a line in the interface file, `iface eth0 inet static`. Below that I have added, `iface eth0 inet dhcp`. Due to that, I'm unable to access my RPi. I have used my Pi ip as `192.168.2.80`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ifconfig` you can see the ipaddress that's currently used by eth0. You can access it through that ip.

Also, if you change the network config, don't forget to restart networking with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

I don't know if it CAN work with 2 settings, but I'd comment one out with putting `#` in front of each line. Also, if it's possible, post your network config. You might have made a mistake

Edit: There's a perfect tutorial here : [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip)